# Vue.js vue-html5-editor

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using browserify and I'm trying to use `vue-html5-editor` https://github.com/PeakTai/vue-html5-editor.

But when I try this:

```
Vue.use(require('vue-html5-editor'));
```

I receive the error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '!!./../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js!./../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=style&index=0!./dashboard.vue' from '/Users/egen/Code/forum/node_modules/vue-html5-editor/dist'
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It just looks like you're missing this dependency.

`npm install css-loader --save`

Or

`npm install css-loader --save-dev`

Both of these commands will install the css-loader npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader

Alternatively - if you're using Yarn, you can use `yarn add css-loader`.

Comment: or `yarn add css-loader --dev`